# Разные версии пакетов при установки npm

Tags: node.js, npm, package

не понимаю почему работает следующим образом. Установлен node js, версии 12.18.3б, и npm версии 6.14.6.В package.json прописано следующее

```
"devDependencies": {
    
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.3",
 
    "serialize-javascript": "^4.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",


  },
```

но в `package-lock.json` пишет cтарые версии

copy-webpack-plugin": {
"version": "5.1.1",
и "serialize-javascript": "^2.1.2",

и появляется ошибка 1 high severity vulnerability о том, обновить нужно serialize-javascript

Comment: Это все зависимости, которые есть в package.json? Если нет, то, возможно, что-то из неуказанного здесь требует для себя старые версии.

Comment: А npm install вы запускали?